# How to use SQL LAG function with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I have a table as the following rows:

[image: here you have a problem illustrator]

```
tipoProtocolo numeroProtocolo dataReferencia dataAssinatura dataVencimento
------------- --------------- -------------- -------------- --------------
1             47676           NULL           20150112       20151231
1             47676           20151231       20150209       NULL
1             47676           NULL           20150224       NULL
1             47676           NULL           20151005       NULL
1             47676           NULL           20151021       NULL
1             47676           NULL           20151026       NULL
1             47676           NULL           20151120       NULL
```

I've implemented a piece of code that gets the value from the dataVencimento column (previous row) to the dataRefencia column (red arrow in the image). However, I would like to check if the column dataVencimento (from the previous row) is NULL. If this condition is true I need to copy the value from the column dataReferencia from the previous row (blue arrow in the image).

```
SELECT tipoProtocolo,
        numeroProtocolo,
            LAG(dataVencimento, 1 ) OVER(
            PARTITION BY numeroProtocolo, tipoProtocolo
            ORDER BY dataAssinatura
            ) dataReferencia,
            dataAssinatura, 
            dataVencimento
FROM cte_ContratoAditivo
```

Here is my SQL code:

```
SELECT tipoProtocolo, numeroProtocolo,
        LAG(dataVencimento, 1) OVER(
        PARTITION BY numeroProtocolo, tipoProtocolo
        ORDER BY dataAssinatura
        ) dataReferencia,
         dataAssinatura, dataVencimento
FROM cte_ContratoAditivo
```

Comment: Could you post the complete expected result for the sample data?

Comment: So if the previous row has a value of `NULL` get the value from 2 rows prior? I *assume* if that row has a value of `NULL`, you want to return that row regardless?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you can use a case statement - `case when <first lag> is null then <second lag>`  kind of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is `lag(ignore nulls)`.  Unfortunately, SQL Server does not support this.

If the dates are increasing, you can use a cumulative max:

```
select . . .,
       max(dataVencimento) over (
            partition by numeroProtocolo, tipoProtocolo
            order by dataAssinatura
            rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
        ) as dataReferencia
```

If this is not the case, you can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select ca.*,
       max(dataVencimento) over (
            partition by numeroProtocolo, tipoProtocolo
            order by dataAssinatura
      ) as dataReferencia
from (select ca.*,
             count(dataVencimento) over (
                partition by numeroProtocolo, tipoProtocolo
                order by dataAssinatura
               ) as grouping
      from cte_ContratoAditivo ca
     ) ca;
```

The subquery counts the number of valid values.  This is really to assign a group number to the rows.  The outer query then spreads the value over the entire group.

Comment: The solution works perfectly. Thanks for the support, Gordon.

Answer (score 0):

As the OP did respond I've gone with the literal and the guessed answer. The first is the literal answer; if the prior row is `NULL` use that the one prior:

```
WITH VTE AS (
    SELECT *    
    FROM (VALUES(1,47676,CONVERT(date,NULL),CONVERT(date,'20150112'),CONVERT(date,'20151231')),
                (1,47676,CONVERT(date,'20151231'),CONVERT(date,'20150209'),CONVERT(date,NULL)),
                (1,47676,CONVERT(date,NULL),CONVERT(date,'20150224'),CONVERT(date,NULL)),
                (1,47676,CONVERT(date,NULL),CONVERT(date,'20151005'),CONVERT(date,NULL)),
                (1,47676,CONVERT(date,NULL),CONVERT(date,'20151021'),CONVERT(date,NULL)),
                (1,47676,CONVERT(date,NULL),CONVERT(date,'20151026'),CONVERT(date,NULL)),
                (1,47676,CONVERT(date,NULL),CONVERT(date,'20151120'),CONVERT(date,NULL))) V(tipoProtocolo,numeroProtocolo,dataReferencia,dataAssinatura,dataVencimento)),
CTE AS(
    SELECT V.tipoProtocolo,
           V.numeroProtocolo,
           V.dataReferencia,
           V.dataAssinatura,
           V.dataVencimento,
           LAG(dataVencimento) OVER (PARTITION BY numeroProtocolo, tipoProtocolo ORDER BY dataAssinatura) AS dataReferencia1,
           LAG(dataVencimento,2) OVER (PARTITION BY numeroProtocolo, tipoProtocolo ORDER BY dataAssinatura) AS dataReferencia2
    FROM VTE V)
SELECT C.tipoProtocolo,
       C.numeroProtocolo,
       C.dataReferencia,
       C.dataAssinatura,
       C.dataVencimento,
       ISNULL(C.dataReferencia1,C.dataReferencia2) AS dataReferencia
FROM CTE C;
```

The other is what I suspect the OP *really* means and that they want the *last* non-`NULL`value. If this is the case, this is a "classic" gaps and islands problem:

```
WITH VTE AS (
    SELECT *    
    FROM (VALUES(1,47676,CONVERT(date,NULL),CONVERT(date,'20150112'),CONVERT(date,'20151231')),
                (1,47676,CONVERT(date,'20151231'),CONVERT(date,'20150209'),CONVERT(date,NULL)),
                (1,47676,CONVERT(date,NULL),CONVERT(date,'20150224'),CONVERT(date,NULL)),
                (1,47676,CONVERT(date,NULL),CONVERT(date,'20151005'),CONVERT(date,NULL)),
                (1,47676,CONVERT(date,NULL),CONVERT(date,'20151021'),CONVERT(date,NULL)),
                (1,47676,CONVERT(date,NULL),CONVERT(date,'20151026'),CONVERT(date,NULL)),
                (1,47676,CONVERT(date,NULL),CONVERT(date,'20151120'),CONVERT(date,NULL))) V(tipoProtocolo,numeroProtocolo,dataReferencia,dataAssinatura,dataVencimento)),
Grps AS(
    SELECT V.tipoProtocolo,
           V.numeroProtocolo,
           V.dataReferencia,
           V.dataAssinatura,
           V.dataVencimento,
           COUNT(dataVencimento)  OVER (PARTITION BY numeroProtocolo, tipoProtocolo ORDER BY dataAssinatura
                                        ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Grp
    FROM VTE V)
SELECT G.tipoProtocolo,
       G.numeroProtocolo,
       G.dataReferencia,
       G.dataAssinatura,
       G.dataVencimento,
       MAX(dataVencimento) OVER (PARTITION BY G.Grp) AS dataReferencia,
       G.Grp
FROM Grps G
ORDER BY dataAssinatura;
```

I will note that is seems odd that you call the column with the `LAG` expression `dataReferencia`, despite that the expression is on `dataVencimento` (and there is already a column called `dataReferencia`).